# Problems downloading Java Extensions with Visual Studio Code Portable

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've installed the portable version of `Visual Studio (VS) Code` onto a USB flash drive, and while I have been able to successfully install some extensions (e.g. `Python`, `Coderunner`, `Debugger for Chrome`), I'm having trouble installing Java extensions. Specifically, the one I've been trying to install is the `Java Extension Pack` (which includes 4 extensions).

After clicking `Install` (in the extension list), I get the following error:

`Failed to install 'vscjava.vscode-java-debug'.`

After clicking the `Download Manually` button, I then get this message:

`Once downloaded, please manually install the downloaded VSIX of 'vscjava.vscode-java-debug'.` (I get the same error for `Maven for Java`, `Java Test Runner`, and the `Java Extension Pack` itself, but with a different filename depending on the extension I'm trying to install)

Lastly, after clicking `Install from VSIX File`, selecting the relevant `.vsix` file, and clicking `Install`, nothing happens. If I restart `VS Code` and search for the extension in the marketplace, the option to `Install` it shows up (which confirms that it wasn't installed properly).

I have been able to download and install `Language Support for Java by Red Hat` individually, but trying to download any of the other extensions from the `Java Extension Pack` (including the `Java Extension Pack` itself) results in the aforementioned error.

Has anyone else had problems with installing extensions in the portable version of `VS Code` (especially Java ones)? If so, how did you overcome them?

Comment: It would be helpful to post error logs faced during download or installation.

Comment: No worries - I've updated the original post to include that information.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the problem by downloading the `VSIX` extension files manually from the [Visual Studio Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode), then installing them by clicking `Options => Install from VSIX` in the `Extensions` tab within VS Code. It took a long time to install them (much longer than it did with the the non-portable version on my laptop), but it did eventually work.